# Multiple jQuery Mobile pages: only the first search input is transformed?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile I have defined 2 pages in my HTML.
Both have a search input:

```
<div id="Page1" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-swatch="a" data-theme="a" data-role="page">
  <input id='Search1' name='Search1' value=''  type='search' placeholder='Search input 1'/>
</div>
<div id="Page2" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a" data-swatch="a" data-theme="a" data-role="page" >
  <input id='Search2' name='Search2' value=''  type='search' placeholder='Search input 2'/>
</div>
```

I switch between those pages, using `hide()` and `show()`. Somehow only the input on the *first* defined page is transformed into a nice jQuery Mobile search input (with magnifier image and clear button).

Any idea why this happens?

***UPDATE***

Found out that I have to use

```
$.mobile.changePage('#Page2');
```

instead of

```
$('#Page2').show();
```

to show the page, otherwise the input on the 2nd page is *not* transformed

***UPDATE 2***

Since changePage() is deprecated, the correct way to change a page is now :

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#Page2', {
    transition: 'flip',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true,
    showLoadMsg: true
});
```

Comment: try to put that in a content div

Comment: Tried that, but didn't make a difference. However it had to do with the way I show and hide the pages, see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use pagecontainer function: https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/